# Installing Android on Nokia Lumia 520 Using MacOS Computer

Tags: rooting, hardware, nokia

I am trying to install Android on my Nokia Lumia 520 so I can use it as a hardware device to debug my apps for Android app development. I use a Macbook Air (MacOS), and tried to search for tutorials to install Android on my Nokia Phone, but I can't find any tutorials for MacOS. Can anyone give me the steps for installing it on my Nokia mobile phone?

Comment: 1) If you watched the videos from https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/android4lumia-android-for-lumia-52x-620-and-720.3985347/ you'll see a Windows program used to flash stock ROM on device, so you'll be better with Apple Boot Camp / Windows install (or get a old PC with Win). 2) You will also note that a number of features on the phone doesn't work with Android ROM including Camera and Accelerometer. For fun sure, for development, avoid any grief/problems and buy a cheap Android phone where everything works and can be used for debugging Android apps.